# Delete the oldest version of the entry

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have a couple of records that look like this:

[image: data records]

TYPE and CODE are each two key fields

My Goal:

[image: data after deleting records]

The ones marked in red are the records that have to be deleted.

How it works:
It should delete the data records which already exist of the TYPE at least 4 times. The smallest CODE should always be deleted. **Important**: CODE is a char3 field.

Does anyone know how I can do that with sql?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain what you mean by "oldest".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "oldest" unless a column specifies that information.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to determine the relevant rows with  
`select TYPE, min(CODE) as CODE from your_table group by TYPE having count(TYPE) > 3`

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL, you can use:

```
delete t from yourtable t
    where (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.type = t.type) >= 4 and
          t.code = (select min(t2.code) from t t2 where t2.type = t.type);
```

There may be alternative ways of formulating this query, depending on the database you are using.

Comment: @demo . . . Yes.  That is an odd question.  `min()` works on almost all data types.